# Indentation error? Python3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Python3 is telling me I have an error in my indentation. I've tried about a million different indentations and I am lost. It's not pointing to the error directly, and just pointing to a parenthesis, leaving me to figure it out on my own.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\Users\\Tom\\Desktop'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            f = open("test.txt", "r+")
            f.seek(0)
        for line in f:
            a = f.read()
            f.seek(0)
        for char in a:
            o = ord(char)
            f.write(str(o))
            f.truncate()
```

Apologies, I forgot to include the error message.

```
File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Search.py", line 6
    f = open("test.txt", "r+")
                             ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Comment: if you use Notepad++, you have to change settings to avoid issuing TABS or it will be a mess...

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: How exactly do I do that, Jean-François Fabre?

Comment: It clearly says **inconsistent use of tabs and spaces** in the error message.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't claiming it was wrong, I was stating that I was unsure where the error was, for it was pointing at a parenthesis and not at an area that was improperly indented. leaving me clueless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I loaded the text from your question into a text editor (vim) and showed invisible characters, which renders this.

[image]

Here, spaces show as space, and tab shows as `^I`. As you can see, your second `for` and first `if` lines are indented with spaces, and the rest of the file is indented with tabs.

In the general sense, this creates a real mess in Python, where indentation is syntactically significant to the program structure.

In Python 3 specifically, mixing tabs and spaces as indentation is a fatal compile error. That is what you've encountered (`TabError`).

See [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces), which suggests using spaces only, never tabs, and using a 4-space indent.

Comment: Nice visual ;-) +1

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me, I had spaces after my indentations, which is a common error for me lol. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I wouldn't normally upvote that, but nice answer. Should be a canonical answer for duplicates.